# Render EPiServer XForm on usual page, not inherited from EPiServer

Tags: c#, episerver, episerver-6

I need to render XForm control on regular page, the one that is not inherited from `TempaltePage`. Currently I'm getting a message:

> Error : Can not create form

With a log entry:

```
ERROR [85] EPiServer.XForms.WebControls.XFormControl.CreateChildControls - 12.6.1 Can not create form
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: virtualPath
       at System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options)
       at EPiServer.XForms.WebControls.XFormControl.CreateChildControls().
```

I cant inherit from TemplatePage because it requires `<head runat="server">` tag, but I'm loading content via ajax and cant have header and other on a page. Is there any way to render XForm in string for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inheriting from EPiServer.SimplePage. That should work.